# Can a CSV file within a WordPress plugin be accessed from the frontend of a website?

Tags: wordpress, csv, security, content-security-policy

I am currently working on an implementation reading data from a csv file from within a WordPress plugin. It was suggested the file be added within the plugin in an assets directory. I have concerns in doing this. In particular, I'm worried about security and whether this makes the site vulnerable to attacks.

That being said, I looked at the assets folder in the frontend on my local environment and was not able to see the csv file.

Does anyone know if adding a csv file directly to a plugin introduce security risks?

Alternatively, I was thinking about uploading this csv to AWS and reading the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Lara.
I am wordpress developer and try to help you now.

We know that every plugin we install should be correct but there are can be some risks.
The wordpress Core do not allow to call CSV and other files directly from folders. For example like assets folder.
But the plugin is third hands software so if a developer do not protect it, anybody can have access to the file.

My advice to check the Stars and Reviews of plugin on
https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Or find reviews of plugin here

https://codecanyon.net/category/all

If it has 4 and more Stars, I think you dont need to worry about security.

Tell please if it helps you...